# TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to update an array on my MongoDB database, but it shows this.
I have tried to follow every step given in the official documentation but it does not work. Please help

Tried the official documentation, didn't work.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// Welcome Page
router.get('/', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));

//DB Config
const db = require('../config/keys').MongoURI;

// Dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    mongoose
        .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    res.render('dashboard', {
        user: req.user
    })
});

router.post('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Book added, Reload to view the changes');
    res.redirect('dashboard')
});

// Add
router.post('/add', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    console.log(name);
    const newBooks = req.user.books;
    newBooks.push(name);
    console.log(newBooks);
    db.users.updateOne(
        {"email" : req.user.email},
        {$set: { "name" : "hello"}});
    res.render('dashboard', {
        user: req.user
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this!**

```
const User = require('../models/users') //important (look for the user model)
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// OUTSIDE !!!!!!!!!!!!
mongoose
.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

//DB Config
const db = require('../config/keys').MongoURI;

router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

    res.render('dashboard', {
        user: req.user
    })
});

outer.post('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Book added, Reload to view the changes');
    res.redirect('dashboard')
});

// Add
router.post('/add', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    console.log(name);
    const newBooks = req.user.books;
    newBooks.push(name);
    console.log(newBooks);
    var email = req.user.email;
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"email" : email},
        {$set: { "name" : "hello"}});
    res.render('dashboard', {
        user: req.user
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a mongoose model method, but you're calling it on a database URI string, by the looks of things.

Instead you need to do something like this:

```
const User = mongoose.model('User');

User.updateOne({"email" : req.user.email},
        {$set: { "name" : "hello"}});
```

The above assumes that your user schema is defined as 'User'.

Comment: Thanks but using this, the changes are only temporary. It is not getting stored on the actual database. What do I do?

Comment: That should be persistent, assuming you've opened a connection to the database first. I see that you only open a connection when navigating to /dashboard; are you sure you've done that before attempting to modify the user?

Comment: Along those lines, I don't recommend connecting to the database within a request. I suggest moving the database connection into the server setup code instead.